# Is there any calcium carbonate analogue drawing carbon from dry air?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, synthesis, solid-state-chemistry

Is there a nonliving (wood does not count) substance or process that accretes a solid material by withdrawing carbon from the air, in a manner analogous to calcium carbonate being accreted from seawater in [biorock/seacrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biorock)?

Comment: The alteration of concrete is an example.

Answer (score 2):

There is no carbon in the air. Air contains some carbon dioxide, but carbon is not carbon dioxide. Carbon is a solid stuff. Carbon dioxide is a gas. Carbon dioxide can be removed from air by bubbling in a suspension of (insoluble) calcium carbonate in water. The reaction occurs according to the equation :  $$\ce{CaCO3  +  CO2  +  H2O  ->  Ca^{2+} + 2 HCO3^-}$$